# R: Calculate local moran's i for points

Tags: r, model, prediction

I have a grid of data points onto which i want to predict a model. I want to account for the base datas variance however and one idea is to use the local moran's i value for each point to do so. 
How can i calculate local moran'i values for each point in my dataset in R. My dataset looks like this (head part):

```
ID        X       Y 
1 1089 383898.2 6546754
2 1090 383908.2 6546754
3 1091 383918.2 6546754
4 1092 383928.2 6546754 
5 1093 383938.2 6546754
6 1094 383948.2 6546754

     BS_STD DEPTH_MEAN  DEPTH_STD DEPTH5_MEAN DEPTH5_STD DEPTH10_MEAN
1.0501265  -30.68537 0.04053959   -30.66645 0.03087045    -30.61544
1.0779848  -30.57806 0.04837730   -30.59313 0.02639191    -30.61459
1.0462083  -30.67739 0.04163193   -30.66867 0.02529867    -30.63884
0.8803281  -30.53063 0.09753478   -30.54041 0.06870715    -30.55129
1.0544024  -30.46543 0.08258441   -30.46609 0.02084569    -30.46282
1.0685774  -30.45120 0.07329989   -30.44605 0.01616248    -30.43023
```